# Basic Netsuite Client Script to Alert based on daysoverdue

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty much just starting out with Javascript/Suitescript.  Trying to work my way up to somewhat practical scripts.  I wrote the script below.  The idea is that if the customer was past due, a simple alert would pop up on screen.  If I navigate to the financial tab of a customer record, it indicates that the field name for days overdue is daysoverdue but the function below is not working.  That field is actually returning undefined.  If I change the field in the alert to companyname, it returns the company name without issue.  I suspect maybe I need to add something to indicate the field is on the financial tab and not the main customer tab.

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType ClientScript
@NModuleScope Public
*/

define([], function() {

function alertPastDue(context) {

    var message = "This customer is past due."
    var daysOverDue = context.currentRecord.getValue({

        "fieldId":"daysoverdue"

    });

alert(context.currentRecord.getValue({"fieldId":"daysoverdue"}))

    
}

return {
    pageInit: alertPastDue
};
});
```

Comment: Hi Steve, You have to write the condition based on trigger type. when record creation days overdue is undefined. Days overdue can be available after completion of due date

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The above has no condition though does it?  I thought the way this would operate is it would just run the function when someone hits edit on the customer page.  I have this script deployed to the customer record.